# How to change the default JRE in tomcat through parellel plesk

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a parallel plesk console. Tomcat version istalled is 7. and JRE also   1.7. But some application is not working. So i need to change JRE 7 to JRE 8.

How it is possible through plesk console?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: Hello Jins, you may want to ask on the more appropriate [superuser site](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

you need to uninstall JDK 7 and re-install JDK8.
for uninstalling java you can refer below links :

http://www.2daygeek.com/remove-uninstall-oracle-java-openjdk-on-ubuntu-centos-debian-fedora-mint-rhel-opensuse/#

https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java

**Install JAVA 8**

First of all, you need to add webupd8team Java PPA repository in your system. After that install, Oracle Java 8 using following a set of commands.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

**Verify Installed Java Version**

After successfully installing Oracle Java using above step verify installed version using the following command.

```
mayank@tecadmin:~$ java -version 

java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

**Configuring Java Environment**

Also, install Java configuration package. It seems like below package is already installed with latest operating systems during installation of JAVA packages. But you can still make sure by running below command.

```
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Now `edit /etc/environment` configuration file and add following entries to set `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` environment variables.

> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
>
> JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre

Comment: We cannot uninstall Tomcat through plesk. That is the problem

Comment: The tomcat is installed in Windows server 12

Comment: I can do it through  the server. But i want to do it through the plesk. then only it will work